# USB 3 adapter keeps disconnecting and reconnecting on MBP 2023 (M2)

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt

Hi I'm moving to a MBP 2018 to a MBP 2023 (M2). I have a very useful usb3 adapter connecting Eth + 3 usb standard ports. I used to rely on it on my MBP 2018 to connect mouse + keyboard + the eth cable.

Now when I connect it to my fresh MBP 2023 (M2), it keeps disconnecting and reconnecting. I am afraid that it could be a problem on the MBP. If I plug the official Apple's [USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF82AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=0b63ae422e8d18f9323b6261ad6d8e0c3f3571427b09d310fd6cbd3092640806ab6a52d33dbbb3628a305227123043575727b7dfc57eca78e9789a7067af9c87261928ea80b2972ac9c2303889a60bc7fcc8878132cb38899ee3cd922894f06e) to the new MBP, all seems working fine.

Are there some known issues like that one on new MBPs? Or maybe my old adapter is simply not compatibile with the new MBP due to thunderbolt 4, or drivers for M2. I'd just like to make sure that there isn't any problem to investigate on the MBP.

Comment: your first step would be to buy another (returnable) ethernet adapter and see how that behaves. Preferably one from a recommended manufacturer (MacWorld, etc.). If that does the same thing *then* I would take the issue to Apple.

Comment: I've found, from years of experience, that Apple-branded adapters (which may include Belkin and Anker brands) work best. We did a study of various adapters a few years ago before rolling out an Anker 7-Port USBC hub (non-Eth, although a newer model has Eth) that has worked flawlessly for more than 2 years in > 80 classrooms and public spaces to connect to projectors a large format LCD panels and provide PD & USBA. MacBooks of many models (up to and including M2) work just fine. I've been testing a Kramer USBC hub KDock-3 for a few months now, and it is my laptop bag for good.

Comment: With another adapter all is working fine. Probably it is a compatibility issue with that specific adapter.